# flash as3 understanding document class paths

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Sorry - I know this has been covered before but I can't get my flash file to locate and use my document class. This is my setup (from the root)

I have a /bin folder containing my published swf and html file (/bin/test.swf).

I have a /resources folder containing an XML file which is loaded (/resources/flar/flarConfig.xml).

I have a /src folder containing my fla (/src/test.fla), and a directory called examples containing the .as file I want to use for my document class (/src/examples/FLARManagerTutorial_2D.as). It looks like this:

```
package examples {

  public class FLARManagerTutorial_2D extends Sprite {

  this.flarManager = new FlarManager("../resources/flar/flarConfig.xml)
```

In my flash publish settings, the class path is just "."

In my document class, if I input: FLARManagerTutorial_2D, I get the error:

```
The name of the package 'examples' does not reflect the location of this file.
```

What do I need to do to get it to recognize and reference this class correctly and load the XML file? I feel like no matter what combination of paths I try, I get the error - or else flash just adds its own blank document class and nothing happens. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your document class to 'examples.FLARManagerTutorial_2D'.

Comment: man - I feel like I did that! Actually, I think I might have set my class folder path to examples/ and my document class to FLARManagerTutorial_2D. So the class path does not change depending on where your SWF is published?

Comment: No it doesn't change. If you add 'examples' to your class folder path then the package structure would change. So, rather than "package example {..." it would be "package {..." and similarly, your document class would be "FLARManagerTutorial_2D" rather than "examples.FLARManagerTutorial_2d". Make sense? @Bosworth99 gave a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Package names are really just a reflection of a file structure.
consider:

```
fla
src/ 
   com/
       mheavers/
                app/
                    FLARManagerTutorial_2D.as
```

The src folder contains the folders com/mheavers/app, which contains your class. This package would then be `com.mheavers.app`. Set the filepath in your fla to src (the parent folder of your package/folder structure), and your document class to `com.mheavers.app.FLARManagerTutorial_2D`.

In your case, make sure a folder called `examples` (that contains your .AS file) exists in your `src` folder if you wish that to be your package, assign the path to src, and set the doc class to `examples.FLARManagerTutorial_2D`.

I definitely had to monkey around with that a bit when I was just getting started with as3. 
Hope that helps.